# How to get span to reset when class not active?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

ok so just to warn you, I know hardly anything about javascript and jquery I just need it for these two buttons at the moment. (For example I have my jquery in to different scripts because I wasn't sure if I could put them in the same one properly [I have my jquery/javascript in my html])

Anyway so my problem is I can't get my span element to go back to how it was before clicking on the parent element when the other class is active. This ends up making the arrows the wrong way if you don't close one of the dropdown forms before opening the other.

ps - you dont need to look at the whole code snippet (just the jquery and the html) unless there is something I have done wrong.

pps - If you looked at the snippet, I know my code is a mess.

```js
$('#login-trigger').click(function() {
  $(this).next('#login-content').slideToggle();
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('#signup-trigger.active').removeClass('active');


  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;')
  else $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;');

  $(this).parent().siblings().children().next().slideUp();
  return false;
});



$('#signup-trigger').click(function() {
  $(this).next('#signup-content').slideToggle();
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('#login-trigger.active').removeClass('active');


  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;')
  else $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;');

  $(this).parent().siblings().children().next().slideUp();
  return false;
});
```

```css
nav {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
nav ul {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 10px 1% 10px 5px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  background: #939393;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
}
nav li {
  float: left;
}
nav #login {
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #fff;
}
nav #login-trigger {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  *zoom: 1;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3E8EC4;
}
nav #login-trigger {
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
nav #login-trigger:hover,
nav #login .active {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
nav #login-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 24px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fff, #eee);
  padding: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
  border-radius: 3px 0 3px 3px;
}
nav li #login-content {
  right: 0;
  width: 264px;
}
/*--------------------*/

#inputs input {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 6px 5px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0px;
  width: 234px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc inset;
}
#inputs input:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #e8c291;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #e8c291 inset;
}
#inputs label {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#inputs label input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 13px;
  margin: auto 1px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
/*--------------------*/

#login #actions {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px;
}
#login #submit2 {
  background-color: #d14545;
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #e97171, #d14545);
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;
  border: 1px solid #7e1515;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font: bold 14px Arial, Helvetica;
  color: #fff;
}
#login #submit2:hover,
#login #submit2:focus {
  background-color: #e97171;
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #d14545, #e97171);
}
#login #submit2:active {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
}
#login #submit2::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: none;
}
#login label {
  float: right;
  line-height: 30px;
}
#login label input {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
}
/*--------------------*/

nav #signup {
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #fff;
}
nav #signup a {
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
nav #signup-trigger {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  *zoom: 1;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3E8EC4;
}
nav #signup-trigger {
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
nav #signup-trigger:hover,
nav #signup .active {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
nav #signup-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 24px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fff, #eee);
  padding: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
  border-radius: 3px 0 3px 3px;
}
nav li #signup-content {
  right: 0;
  width: 264px;
}
#signup #actions {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px;
}
#signup #submit2 {
  background-color: #d14545;
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #e97171, #d14545);
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;
  border: 1px solid #7e1515;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 150px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font: bold 14px Arial, Helvetica;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
#signup #submit2:hover,
#signup #submit2:focus {
  background-color: #e97171;
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #d14545, #e97171);
}
#signup #submit2:active {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
}
#signup #submit2::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: none;
}
#signup label {
  float: right;
  line-height: 30px;
}
#signup label input {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li id="login">
      <a id="login-trigger" href="#">
        Log in <span>▼</span>
      </a>
      <div id="login-content">
        <form>
          <fieldset id="inputs" style="padding-right: 6px; padding-left: 6px; padding-top: 10px;">
            <input id="username" type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Your email address" required>
            <input id="password" type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" required>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset id="actions">
            <input type="submit" id="submit2" value="Log in">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">Keep me signed in</label>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="signup">
      <a id="signup-trigger" href="#">
        Sign Up <span>▼</span>
      </a>
      <div id="signup-content">
        <form>
          <fieldset id="inputs" style="padding-right: 6px; padding-left: 6px; padding-top: 10px;">
            <input id="username" type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Your email address" required>
            <input id="password" type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" required>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset id="actions">
            <input type="submit" id="submit2" value="signup">
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: use addClass() to add the class and removeClass() to remove class and toggleClass(), hmm I dont use much lol.

Comment: `ok so just to warn you,` I am so scary !

Comment: M scared more than to that BIG CODE rather then the words "Warn you".. :p and bdw what doest it mean PPS ??

Comment: it means post post script (basically just after P.S)

Answer (score 0):

Like this, the classic flip - flop, add one, remove the other.

```
 $('#login-trigger').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
    var other = $('#signup-trigger'); //adding this makes it more readable and caches the jQuery object for a teeny tiny speed improvement 

    //slide this content down
    $(this).next('#login-content').slideDown();
    //slide that content up
    $('#signup-content').slideUp();

    //add to this
    $(this).addClass('active');
    //remove from that
    other.removeClass('active');

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;');
        other.find('span').html('&#x25BC;');//< swap the other link's arrow!
    }else{
        $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;');
         other.find('span').html('&#x25B2;');
    }
    return false;
});

$('#signup-trigger').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var other = $('#login-trigger');
    //slide this content down
    $(this).next('#signup-content').slideDown();
    //slide that content up
    $('#login-content').slideUp();

    //add to this
    $(this).addClass('active');
    //remove from that
    other.removeClass('active');

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;');
        other.find('span').html('&#x25BC;'); 
    }else{
        $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;');
         other.find('span').html('&#x25B2;');
    }
    return false;
 });
```

I'm assuming this

```
 $(this).parent().siblings().children().next().slideUp();
```

Was correlated to ( but opposite of )

```
 $(this).next('#login-content').slideToggle();
```

If you follow. ( basically the content of the other one )

Anyway, if it wasn't I would suggest adding an ID on that and making your life simpler because that `$(this).parent().siblings().children().next().slideUp();` is really ugly.

Toggling is great but it's easy to lose control of the state of the toggle, especially when mixing the manual moves with the automatic, so if you have to manually move it just take full control of it.

I added event.preventDefault() as even though it returns false, these are links and it's just a best practice sort of thing to prevent the link from reloading the page.

the problem with the arrows was you were not changing them in the other one.

Try this
https://jsfiddle.net/k8y68606/1/

But also notice how I rearranged things to make it more readable.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not sure what that line is for I got help from someone for these buttons and that was there (also so I know; is that line just saying for everything related to do the opposite?). Also when I replaced what I had with what you wrote neither tab dropped down. Do I need to change something?

Comment: I'm sure you will have to change a few things, I was just doing some clean up.   Didn't really test it.

Comment: @eamonbutler ~ I updated the answer and included a jsFiddle link with it working.  There is also a bunch of unclosed input tags in your html such as <input type="... > should end with />, not a serious problem.  But I try to be accurate.

Comment: oh I always learnt that you didn't need to close input's like that.

Comment: ok I tried it out and while I was testing it I think I realised what the last line was meant for, return it back when clicked again. I'm not sure if you knew this already but to be able to do this again do I just add it back in?

Comment: no the last line is really this line $('#signup-content').slideUp(); or  $('#login-content').slideUp(); in the other one.

Comment: I found that it was slide toggle in the first place so that it could be clicked to go up and down, and this is where the problem has been all along. For some reason when it slides up from toggling it doesnt see it as no longer active so the arrow doesnt change. Do you or anyone else know how to fix this? (I changed the slideDown to slideToggle so that it works both ways).